# Finding bounds of integration for double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am working on the following problem:

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surface$f(x,y)=4-x^2-y$ and the constraint $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$

In calculating this volume I suspect that I shall be constructing a double integral with the following bounds: $\int_{0}^{y_{max}}\int_{0}^{f(x)}dxdy$, as the "base" of my solid will be my bound of $y=0$, and the "upper" of this solid shall be given by my surface $f(x,y)$ $\textbf{but I am struggling to calculate the latter bound.}$ Unlike similar 2 dimensional problems where I can express $y$ in terms of $x$ to determine the bounds across which I shall evaluate $y$, I am here working with a multivariable function.

Much thanks.

Comment: Is that problem written exactly as it appears? The graph of that function goes down forever as $x$ increases, so there is no finite solid bounded by just $x$ and $y$ being nonnegative. I suspect they meant to also say $z\ge0$. If so, then you can consider setting the function equal to zero to help figure out your bounds of integration.